# Kotlin - HibernateProxy not loaded when calling a getter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I'm currently converting an existing Java project to Kotlin, and I'm running into some issues about Hibernate Lazy Loading behavior.

In the following data model (simplified) :

```
@Entity
open class Parent
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long = 0

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], optional = false)
    open var child = Child(this)
}

@Entity
open class Child(@MapsId
                 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                 @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
                 val parent: Parent)
{
    @Id
    private val parentId: Long = 0

    // Its actual type is not relevant, as long as it is not a primitive type
    var whateverAttributeFromChild: AnyComplexType
}
```

The Lazy Loading seem to work as expected (when I query a `Parent`, the `child` attribute is represented by a subclass of `HibernateProxy`, and in the database, the `Child` table is not queried).

However, when I run `parent.child` in my application, Hibernate does not load the child.
That means : If I call `parent.child.whateverAttributeFromChild`, the `whateverAttributeFromChild` will be NULL (because it is not loaded).

I can't find a way to tell Hibernate to load the lazy attributes when accessed (and I don't want to manually unproxy every lazy attribute from my application).

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't understand your mapping on the child attribute in Parent you have mappedBy. Why do you use a JoinColumn there? Try to remove this

Comment: You're right, that was a mistake from the previous developer I migrated the code from :) I removed it, same problem. I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

In addition of the `open` keyword on the `@Entity` class itself, ALL attributes should be `open` as well ! When adding the `open` keyword to the `Child.whateverAttributeFromChild` attribute, the lazy loading worked as expected !

So don't forget to open your attributes !!